# C++ functor as a function pointer

Tags: c++, windows, functor

I have a Functor which I need to send to a function which receives a function pointer as a parameter (such as `CreateThread`).

Can I convert it to a static method address somehow? And if not, how can I do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you can't convert a class-type object to a function pointer.

However, you can write a non-member wrapper function that calls the member function on the right instance.  Many APIs, including `CreateThread`, allow you to provide a pointer that it will give back to you when it calls your callback (for `CreateThread`, this is the `lpParameter` parameter).  For example:

```
DWORD WINAPI FunctorWrapper(LPVOID p)
{
    // Call operator() on the functor pointed to by p:
    return (*static_cast<FunctorType*>(p))();
}

// Used as:
FunctorType f;
CreateThread(0, 0, &FunctorWrapper, &f, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I do now, but If I have 2 instances of the class which uses "CreateThread", I'll have to use mutexes so it won't cause a mess and it will slow me down. I'm not talking only about createthread but in general.

Comment: Why do you need a mutex?  You tell `CreateThread` what pointer to give back to you...

Comment: But if I call it from 2 different threads at the same time, the  pointer from the second thread might "overrun" the one from the first thread... :/

Comment: Not to mention that you could use a sane C++ API for threading, and you could replace `CreateThread` with something that accepts a functor in the first place. :)

Comment: @jalf:  Well, right:  if possible, one should just use Boost.Thread or just::thread.  It took me three tries to get the right signature for my ThreadProc :-O

Comment: @Idov: no, each call to the function gets its own set of parameters. They're not shared with other invocations of the function.

Comment: @ldov:  I don't understand:  do you want each thread to have its own instance of the functor?  If so, create a different instance for each thread.  Do you want all the threads to share access to the same functor?  If so, create one and synchronize access to it using a mutex or some other synchronization method...

Comment: @James McNellis: Ok, each thread has its own instance (so no syncronization needed). thanks :)

Comment: I don't quite understand what is `FunctorType` - a function-pointer? Or a class? If it is function-pointer then why are you passing it via address? And if it class, how can you pass the address of local?

Comment: @AJay:  It is a class type with an `operator()` overload.  There is nothing wrong with taking the address of a local variable.  The caller of `CreateThread()` is responsible for ensuring that `f` exists for at least as long as the thread may use it.

Comment: That means launching a different thread and waiting for it till it completes (results in synchrounous operation).

Comment: @Ajay:  How is that in any way synchronous?  The caller of `CreateThread()` is free to continue execution after making the call.  That said, there's no reason it has to be a local variable; it could just as well be dynamically allocated or static.

Comment: @James: "it could just as well be dynamically allocated or static" - Exactly! But shouldn't be a local, otherwise WFSO, WFMO, SleepEx or other API would be called to ensure that stack allocated variable (if more than sizeof(viod*)) remain. You may create many threads, and then finally call WFMO on all of them to reduce synchronous-ness, but essentially that has to be syncronous!